# My Spring Boot server returns 406 Http error code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot server application that receives a POST request from an external service with the following characteristics:

**Headers**

```
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
user-agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)
connection: Keep-Alive
host: webhook.site
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length: 558
Query strings: (empty)
```

**Form values**

```
BillNumber: 41492032464
BillValue: 600000.0
Description: Description
```

To be able to handle this POST request from the external service I implemented the following controller, which what it does is create and store an invoice, but my application returns an HTTP Error 406:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bills", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public void createBill(UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder,
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
}
```

I understand that the error refers to the client (in this case the external service) does not understand the "language" of the server response, but as you can see in the headers of my controller I am accepting "application / x-www-form -urlencoded". I do not know if it's due to another problem also my controller it's void.

How should this controller be implemented in my spring boot app?

Comment: No, it means that the server can't generate what the client is asking for. You're mixing up Accept (here's what I want back) and Content-Type (here's what I'm sending) headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `consumes` with [`MediaType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) to define the supported `Content-Type`. You can further simplify by using [`@PostMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/bills", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
```

It's pointless to set `Accept` header on response like you do now, this is a request header. As per [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept):

> The `Accept` request HTTP header advertises which content types, expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand. Using content negotiation, the server then selects one of the proposals, uses it and informs the client of its choice with the `Content-Type` response header. Browsers set adequate values for this header depending on the context where the request is done: when fetching a CSS stylesheet a different value is set for the request than when fetching an image, video or a script.